# IP SLA VS tracking IP-route reachability for HSRP

Tags: cisco-ios, hsrp

I have two Cisco switches A and B, which I want to use HSRP to track if route to specific IP still works, but according to my understand it could be either IP SLA or tracking IP-Route Reachability method, what's the pros and cons on both method?

IP SLA method:
[image]

Track IP-Route reachability method:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRR basically checks for a route, presumably learned from a dynamic routing protocol, but a down interface results in routes being removed as well.

SLA can check a variety of methods -- ICMP-echo being very common. And it can check things in more depth -- eg. HTTP, pings to more distant points, etc.

Comment: RTTMON MIB lists 18 different types. Not all of them are supported everywhere. Also, one of them is "script", so it's a very extensive mechanism.